# If list1 has any items of list2

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

Assume we have the following two lists,

`list1 = ['text_svm_a', 'football_04', 'nice_sensor']`

`list2 = ['svm', 'sensor']`

```
filtered_list = [item for item in list1 if item_contains_any_of_items_in_list2]
```

any help on writing `item_contains_any_of_items_in_list2` is really appreciated.

**Note:** Both lists could be large so I don't want to hard code each condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
filtered_list = [item for item in list1 if any(x in item for x in list2)]
# ['text_svm_a', 'nice_sensor']
```